# Jest React: How to mock window eventListener set in componentDidMount

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, enzyme

Here I need to add tests for handleBeforeUnload in window eventListener but I am getting error, How will I resolve it?

```
   expect(jest.fn())[.not].toHaveBeenCalled()

    Matcher error: received value must be a mock or spy function

    Received has value: undefined

    map.beforeunload();
    
   expect(wrapper.handleBeforeUnload).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

My component

```
componentDidMount() {
       window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
      this.handleBeforeUnload();
    });
}

handleBeforeUnload () {
}
```

My test spec:

```
  it('should call handleBeforeUnload', () => {
    const historyMock = { listen: jest.fn(), replace: jest.fn() };
    const map = {};
    window.addEventListener = jest.fn((event, cb) => {
      map[event] = cb;
    });
    const wrapper = shallow(
      <AppRoutes history={historyMock} getDctkConfig={getDctkConfig} />,
    );

    map.beforeunload();

    expect(wrapper.handleBeforeUnload).toHaveBeenCalled();

  });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You didn't spy the`.handleBeforeUnload()` method of the component class. You can spy it through `Component.prototype.handleBeforeUnload`. Besides, you can mock the implementation of the `.addEventListener()` method and invoke the listener function manually.

`index.tsx`:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

export default class AppRoutes extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', (event) => {
      this.handleBeforeUnload();
    });
  }

  handleBeforeUnload() {}

  render() {
    return <div>app routes</div>;
  }
}
```

`index.test.tsx`:

```
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import React from 'react';
import AppRoutes from './';

describe('69346085', () => {
  afterEach(() => {
    jest.restoreAllMocks();
  });
  test('should pass', () => {
    const handleBeforeUnloadSpy = jest.spyOn(AppRoutes.prototype, 'handleBeforeUnload');
    jest
      .spyOn(window, 'addEventListener')
      .mockImplementation((type: string, listener: EventListenerOrEventListenerObject) => {
        typeof listener === 'function' && listener({} as Event);
      });
    shallow(<AppRoutes />);

    expect(handleBeforeUnloadSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
  });
});
```

test result:

```
PASS  examples/69346085/index.test.tsx (9.191 s)
  69346085
    ✓ should pass (7 ms)

-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
File       | % Stmts | % Branch | % Funcs | % Lines | Uncovered Line #s 
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
All files  |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
 index.tsx |     100 |      100 |     100 |     100 |                   
-----------|---------|----------|---------|---------|-------------------
Test Suites: 1 passed, 1 total
Tests:       1 passed, 1 total
Snapshots:   0 total
Time:        9.814 s, estimated 10 s
```